# Phonegap/JQuery HTML not rendered correctly

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using Ajax to gather HTML from a webserver, which is then used to populate a div within the app. The HTML populates, however the CSS is ignored and whats displayed is a plain HTML output to the screen instead of the JQuery CSS. Thing is, when I manually enter the HTML into the div and then load up the whole thing works great. Any help is greatly appreciated

Ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.mydomain.com/getDetails.php",
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(text_results){
                    console.log(text_results);          
                    $('.class-items').append(text_results);                 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And the div being populated:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="class-items">

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=jquery+style+dynamic+content

Answer (score 0):

I think that jQuery on() might help here:

http://api.jquery.com/on/